# Set Global CSS Style Sheet in JavaFX with fxml and SceneBuilder

Tags: java, css, javafx, global, javafx-8

How do I set a global css style sheet ?
I'm using fxml and scene builder.
I added it to resources directory in my project and

`<BorderPane fx:id="mainBorder" onDragDetected="#minimize" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="700.0"
            style="-fx-background-color: white;" stylesheets="../../../../../../resources/css/JTheme.css"
            xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
            fx:controller="com.s.c.desktop.template.RootLayoutController">`

But it doesn't work :(.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `@` in your url.

Try to replace your stylesheets with :

```
stylesheets="@../../../../../../resources/css/JTheme.css"
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work but My idea knows it :(

Comment: Are you sure of the path? Can you attach a project direct snapshot on your question?

Comment: Yes path is true,When i mouse over on this with pressing shift key it goes to the class.
Also scenebuilder knows it by when I run it it doesn't bind css class.

Comment: Goes to the class? I am talking about the css path here.

Comment: i.e css class path .I do that work in intellij idea.

Comment: worked for me with a change @../../../../../../css/  instead of @../../../../../../resources/css/.  I had to remove the /resources/ from the path